# ¿Cómo se podría hacer que un RadioButton de VisualStudio (c#) tenga dos estados?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Cómo se podría realizar un Radio button o si tengo que utilizar un button normal, que tenga dos estados, es decir cuando pulso (ON) realizara una funcion X y si vuelvo a pulsar(OFF) parara de realizar una función X.

¿Hay alguna manera de realizarlo? Mi código es este. Sé que esta mal porque además no funciona.

```
private void RecopilarInformacion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        // no es viable, mirar bien esta parte, esta casi pero ralentiza mucho la app
        if(RecopilarInformacion.IsChecked==true)
        { click = 1; }

        if(RecopilarInformacion.IsChecked==false)
        {
            click = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: El objeto sender contiene el radio button por lo que puedes obtenerlo y comprobar su estado.

Comment: si, el estado lo puedo comprobar pero no consigo modificarlo

Comment: Define modificarlo.

Comment: es decir, que cuando pulso el circulo hueco de radio button se queda "lleno", pues cuando vuelvo a pulsar "sigue igual" y quiero que desaparezca (osea desactivarlo) no se si me explico bien

Comment: El RadioButton es un control diseñado para opciones múltiples mutuamente excluyentes, una ves que lo activas en tiempo de ejecución la manera de desactivarlo es seleccionando otro RadioButton que se encuentre en el mismo Canvas (form, grupbox, picture); generalmente para status activo e inactivo se usa el control CheckBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes un radiobutton llamado `rbPrueba` con el evento `RecopilarInformacion_Click`:

```
private void RecopilarInformacion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.rbPrueba.Checked)
         funcionX();
        else
         funcionY();
    }
```

Compruebas si el radiobutton esta `checked`, si lo está ejecutará `funcionX` que lo encienda, sino la `funcionY` que lo apague.
Dentro de las funciones es donde harías la lógica.

--

Editado para responder al comentario:

funcionX:

```
public void funcionX(){
  //Haces la lógica que creas conveniente
}
```

Si quieres desactivar/activar el radiobutton:

```
this.rbPrueba.Checked = true; //false para desactivarlo
```

Comment: cuando te refieres dentro de la functionX, osea creo una con sus{} o como?, con lo de checked lo he probado, pero no me deja quitarle el punto al RadioButton cuando intento volver a clickar, no se si me explico muy bien

Comment: Editado con lo que pides

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza un ToggleButton, que también es parte de los controles de WPF

```
<ToggleButton Click="ToggleButton_Click"/>
```

Y este es el code behind (**EDITADO**)

```
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton tb = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton;
        if (tb.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            // Codigo para IsChecked
        }
        else
        {
            // Código para el evento contrario
        }
}
```

Y con eso puedes obtener el resultado que quieres, también lo puedes declarar así:

```
<ToggleButton Checked="toggleButton_IsCheckedChanged"  Unchecked="toggleButton_IsCheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: en la secuencia if((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked), el toggleButton no me lo identifica y si pongo el nombre de mi control tampoco lo identifica

Comment: Ahí edité la respuesta, solo hay que declarar el ToggleButton con su namespace completo, y el IsChecked con .Value ya que es nulificable.